# SQLSTATE[HY000] [335544721] Unable to complete network request to host

Tags: laravel, connection, firebird

I have a issue when recovering the data from a Firebird database, whose server is on a computer with Windows Server 2019 operating system.

I'm using the "harrygulliford / laravel-firebird" package to get the connection. From my local computer (Windows 10), it works perfectly, but when deploying it in a hosting service that has a Linux operating system, I get the error SQLSTATE [HY000] [335544721] Unable to complete network request to host "xxx. xxx.xxx.xxx ".

I suspect that it may be due to the difference in operating systems, but I cannot find the specific issue.

Here the .env configuration

```
DB_CONNECTION = firebird
DB_HOSTFB = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DB_PORTFB = 3050
DB_DATABASEFB = 'D:\TESTDATABASE\2021.GDB'
DB_USERNAMEFB = SYSDBA
DB_PASSWORDFB = masterkey
DB_CHARSETFB = UTF8
DB_VERSIONFB = 2.5
```

Comment: Did you check firewall rules and logs? Is host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx reachable from hosting machine at all?

Comment: use TCP/IP sniffer like WireShark or Microsoft NEtwork Monitor to see the Firebird connection sequence, starting from the client machine up to server, to check which stage and in which junction point fails

Comment: Hello, as I mentioned, it is not a problem of ports since from my local machine I can access without any problem, also in the remote server the firewall is completely off. I have used the firebird trace but apparently no connection reaches the remote machine. I will try the recommended WireShark option

Comment: The fact your local machine can connect to port 3050 on the server with Firebird, does not mean your hosting service can connect to the server with Firebird, a secure network setup would disallow such connections unless specifically configured (e.g. using IP whitelisting or VPNs).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Thanks for your comment, I really don't know about the rules in requests between servers, can you please tell me how to verify what you say?, I emphasize that the firewall is disabled on the server

Comment: This really depends on the IP address used, if both your hosting and the database server are on the same network, which IP address(es) the Firebird server process is bound to, if the IP address you use is publicly routable or from a private address range, if there is a firewall between your network and the network of the hosting service, how it is configured, etc, etc. This is not really a programming question, probably  not even a Firebird question, but more a network configuration and routing question. My first suggestion would be: talk to your network operations team.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel both my local machine, the host and the server belong to different networks, I have thought that one of the problems is because it is a shared host. I will continue investigating focusing on networks rather than development as you advise. Thank you